# Problema al usar header con MVC

Tags: php, mvc

La idea es que al ingresar un usuario correctamente, es decir, que existe su `usuario` y `contraseña` en la base de datos, esta me redirija a otra página. Pero me sale el siguiente *Warning*:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information  - headers already sent by ...

Estoy implementando `MVC`:

- **Vista:**

```
<form method="POST">
        <!-- usuario -->
        <div class="group validarIngreso"> 
            <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" maxlength="6" required>
            <span class="highlight"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <label><i class="fas fa-user-tie"></i> USUARIO</label>
        </div>

        <!-- contraseña -->
        <div class="group validarIngreso">
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" pattern="(?=.*[a-z]).{6,}" required>
            <span class="highlight"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <label><i class="fas fa-key"></i> CONTRASEÑA</label>
        </div>
        <span class="text-danger p-2" id="error"></span>

        <?php 
            $ingreso = new Controllers();
            $ingreso->ingresoUsuarioController();
        ?>
</div>

<!-- botones del modal -->
<div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-entrar" id="enviar">INGRESAR</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

- **Controlador:**

```
class Controllers
{
    public function ingresoUsuarioController()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['usuario']))
        {
            $datosController = array(
                "usuario" => $_POST['usuario'],
                "password" => $_POST['password']
            );

            $respuesta = Model::ingresoUsuarioModel($datosController, "usuarios");

            // var_dump($respuesta);

            if($respuesta['ba'] == $_POST['usuario'] &&
               $respuesta['password'] == $_POST['password'] )
            {
                header("location:views/dashboard.php");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- **Modelo:**

```
class Model
{
    public static function ingresoUsuarioModel($datosModel, $tabla)
    {
        $stmt = MySql::Conectar()->prepare("select ba, password from $tabla where ba = :usuario");
        $stmt->bindParam(":usuario", $datosModel['usuario'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}
```

La **vista** seria mi `index.php` y mis carpetas están distribuidas de la siguiente manera:

[image: archivos]

Comment: ¿Tienes etiquetas de cierre `?>` en tus ficheros PHP?

Comment: ¿Falla con esta línea comentada `// var_dump($respuesta);`?

Comment: ¿Hay espacios antes de abrir el tag de PHP?

Comment: Si tu Index.php es la vista, entonces ahí tienes el error. Seguramente cuando haces el POST. El asunto es que primero dibujas un html, con lo que ya se han pasado los headers. Luego cargas una clase PHP y llamas a la función que comprueba si es un post.  Si es correcto intentas cambiar los headers... Y ya no puedes..  es decir, en este caso no está bien implementado el mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si bien no es una forma correcta de MVC, voy a plantearte una posible solución a tu problema.

lo primero, el index.php debe ser un "enrutador" que analice la ruta y te derive al controlador correcto. Esto me lo voy a saltar (te lo dejo a tu criterio para implementarlo)

vamos a utilizar como index.php tu controller. Pero le vamos a cambiar añadiendo dos headers distintos: uno para el formulario y otro para tu dashboard. Al final, lo "ejecutamos":

```
class Controllers
{
    public function ingresoUsuarioController()
    {
        $template = "views/login.php";

        if(isset($_POST['usuario']))
        {
            $datosController = array(
                "usuario" => $_POST['usuario'],
                "password" => $_POST['password']
            );

            $respuesta = Model::ingresoUsuarioModel($datosController, "usuarios");

            // var_dump($respuesta);
            if($respuesta['ba'] == $_POST['usuario'] &&
               $respuesta['password'] == $_POST['password'] )
            {
                $template = "views/dashboard.php";
            }
        }
        headers("location:".$template);
    }
}
$ingreso = new Controllers();
$ingreso->ingresoUsuarioController();
```

tu plantilla "views/login.php" deberia ser la misma, quitando las partes de php (y añadiendo el action correspondiente):

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
        <!-- usuario -->
        <div class="group validarIngreso"> 
            <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" maxlength="6" required>
            <span class="highlight"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <label><i class="fas fa-user-tie"></i> USUARIO</label>
        </div>

        <!-- contraseña -->
        <div class="group validarIngreso">
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" pattern="(?=.*[a-z]).{6,}" required>
            <span class="highlight"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <label><i class="fas fa-key"></i> CONTRASEÑA</label>
        </div>
        <span class="text-danger p-2" id="error"></span>
</div>

<!-- botones del modal -->
<div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-entrar" id="enviar">INGRESAR</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Tu plantilla de "views/dashboard.php" seria la misma que tengas.

**EXPLICACION:**

Cuando se inicia index.php, se define la clase, se crea un objeto y se ejecuta el metodo `ingresoUsuarioController`.

Dentro del metodo comprobamos si hay un POST. Si es asi evaluamos el formulario (con el modelo) y si es correcto vamos a la plantilla dashboard. En  caso erroneo, o que no hay post, se redirige a la plantilla por defecto (en este caso login.php)

En este caso, estamos ejecutando directamente el index.php, NO ENVIAMOS nada en los headers hasta que se llama a las vistas (cuando se ejecuta headers). al redirigir a las vistas, que son html, ya se envia lo necesario.

**DESTACAR DOS COSAS:**

1.- no es del todo correcto, puesto que este index.php solo va a funcionar en la parte de login. Tu archivo dashboard.php debera tener otro class "dashboardController" y ejecutar al final el metodo correspondiente. Eso va a ser complicar el proceso. Revisa como hacer un enrutador, para que en funcion de la url y del metodo se ejecute uno u otro controller.

2.- las plantillas no deberian tener codigo php, o si necesitas dibujar varias cosas dependiendo de variables, es mejor que implementes un lenguaje de plantillas (yo te plantearia twig).

Por ultimo, te plantearia que revises diversos frameworks (symfony, laravel, codeiginiter...) para ver como se aplica MVC, e incluso que empieces a usar alguno de ellos. Poco a poco veras lo util y sencillo que resulta el MVC :)

Comment: +1, muchas gracias, tu explicación quedo clara y el método funciono correctamente!

Answer (score 0):

Probá usando *ob_start();* en la página donde tengas este inconveniente, ya que se trata de un problema con las cabeceras (*headers*).